# Get an integer vector from a multi-line text file

Tags: java, parsing, integer

I need to parse a `.txt` file to three double arrays. This files has various lines. In each line there are three integes divided by space.

Example:

```
19.1    24.3    0
18.2    24.0    0
12.6    24.9    20
14.4    28.0    20
```

My goal is to get three double array (`x`, `y` and `z`) and in each array there should be a column. So the result should be the same of writing the following instructions:

```
double[] x = {19.1,18.2,12.6,14.4};
double[] y = {24.3,24.0,24.9,28.0};
double[] z = {0,0,20,20};
```

I know how to open and read files, something like this:

```
String file = "filename.txt";
String line=null;
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while(!(line=br.readLine()).contains("EOF")) {
  // read and process one line..
}
```

What I don't know how to do is how to parse each number of the current line and assign it to one of the three vectors.

Comment: You may want to have a look into [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: Why don't you read the file until the end, instead of reading it untile some line contains EOF?

Comment: well,because I use to do it since VB6 but you are right. Also Scanner Class is a good possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply split and parse each line as follows:

```
String[] row = line.split("\\s+");
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(row[0]);
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(row[1]);
double d3 = Double.parseDouble(row[2]);
```

Also, if the number of lines is not fixed then it will be easier and makes more sense to use `ArrayList`s of `Double`s instead of arrays of `double`s.

Comment: well.my code is not complete so I can't test it. However thank you and I'll accept your answer

Comment: @dragonmnl: Just like JB Nizet said in his comment above, is that "EOF" really going to be in your input file. I am asking this because, I don't see one in the sample above.